# What is the purpose of the "SQUIDINTERNAL" string in URLs

Tags: squid

I have seen the string "SQUIDINTERNAL" appear in numerous script examples for caching videos using Squid, however none of them explain why they have used the "SQUIDINTERNAL" string appended on the domain, for example: `http://video-srv.youtube.com.SQUIDINTERNAL/`

What is the purpose of using it?

Here is an example script: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/StoreUrlRewrite/RewriteScript

Answer (score 1):

After more than a year I have found the answer, buried [here](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent/Coordinator#CDN.2BAFw-DNS_load_balancing).

> Many websites use CDN(Content Delivery Network) to scale their website. Some of these are using the same URL on other domains. One of the major opensource players that I can demonstrate with is SourceForge. They have mirrors all over the world and they use a prefix domain to select the mirror like:
>
> > `http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/assp/ASSP%20Installation/README.txt`
> > `http://cdnetworks-kr-2.dl.sourceforge.net/project/assp/ASSP%20Installation/README.txt`
>
> So this is a case of Simple URL de-duplication. This scenario can be resolved easily by storing all of the sub-domains under one "key". Kind of like a pseudo for this: every subdomain of `dl.sourceforge.net` should be stored as: `dl.sourceforge.net.some_internal_key`. and a ruby example to demonstrate code for that:
>
> > `url =` 
> > `"http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/assp/ASSP%20Installation/README.txt"`
> >
> > `key = "http://dl.sourceforge.net.squid.internal/" +` `url.match(/.*\.dl\.sourceforge\.net\/(.*)/)[1]`